# Handling when format-date() tries to format an invalid date in XSL

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I need to format a date using XSL. For example:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$rawdate">
            <xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:date" select="$rawdate"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date($dt, '[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y0001]')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            N/A
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This will work if `$rawdate` is formatted correctly (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD). However, if its formatting incorrectly (such as DD-MM-YYYY), the `format-date()` function fails and processing stops. `$rawdate` is coming from an XML file that is edited by hand, so it's possible for someone to unintentially format the date wrong.

What I want to do is catch when `format-date()` is going to fail (or already failed) so I can handle it gracefully instead of halting the transformation. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't you get a problem with `<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:date" select="$rawdate"/>` if the date is in the wrong format? Anyway, you can check `$rawdate castable as xs:date` to check whether it can be parsed as an `xs:date`.

Comment: `$rawdate castable as xs:date` was exactly what I needed! If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Note, it's not format-date() that fails, it's the creation of the xs:date instance supplied as input to format-date(). The format-date() function requires an xs:date instance as input, and once you have such an instance, it can't possibly be invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `castable as xs:date`

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$rawdate castable as xs:date">
        <xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:date" select="$rawdate"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date($dt, '[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y0001]')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        N/A
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```